# How to remove /shop or /product in URL WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, permalinks

I'm working on WordPress site and I use WooCommerce plugin. This plugin rewrites all my URLs like

```
www.mydomain.com/product/category/postname/
```

but my client want to remove the `/product/` folder.
By default the Permalink Settings in WordPress can't do that and WooCommerce team also [recommended](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/) not to remove the `/product/` folder. But I want my URL be like

```
www.mydomain.com/category/subcategory/post_id/postname/
```

Can anyone help, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried many ways to do this finally i found a plugin [Remove slug from custom post type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/) This works for me but this plugin is an old one and untested with my wordpress version. How ever its works for me.

Answer (score 1):

User the Custom Permalink Plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: Please share your details i will fix it

Comment: If this is a plugin that you wrote, you need to *explicitly* disclose that in the answer. Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin out https://wubpress.com/

I know that it costs 20$ and you might be looking for a free option, but believe me sometimes is better pay 20 and run than coding or applying someone else's code that might not work 100% and does not give support over his code.

Just to be clear, i have nothing to do with this plugin, just helping here.

Comment: Thanks But i can't spent money for this